# Run out of proc com server as specific user

Tags: c++, com, access-rights

I have an out of proc com server , how can i register (regserver) in such a way that , if this process runs then it runs as a specific user. 
For eg : Currently i run as User A and do the registration of this com server and when this process is started it should run under the User B.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using dcomcnfg.exe, [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).